# enqueuing external and internal js and css in wordpress did not work with owl.js animate.css

Tags: theme-development, javascript

```
<?php
function cadentic_files () {

    wp_enqueue_script('cadentic_owl_carousel',get_theme_file_uri('js/owl.carousel.min.js'), array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('cadentic_wow_carousel',get_theme_file_uri('js/wow.min.js'), array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('cadentic_jquery_carousel',get_theme_file_uri('js/jquery-multitabs.js'), array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('cadentic_jquery1113_carousel',get_theme_file_uri('js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'), array('jquery'), time(), true );
    //wp_enqueue_script('cadentic_bootstrap_carousel',get_theme_file_uri('js/bootstrap.min.js'), array('jquery'), time(), true );
    
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_font_awesome','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,600,700,900', false);
    
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_font_popins','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700', false);
    
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_font_confortaa','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:300,400,700|Josefin+Sans:100i,300,400,700|Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900', false);
    
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_main_styles',get_stylesheet_uri(), false);
    
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_animate_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/animate.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_owl_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/owl.theme.default.min.css'), false);
    //wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_owlcarousel_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/owl.carousel.min.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_bootstrap_theme_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_jquery_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/jquery-multitabs.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_font_awesome_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/font-awesome.min.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_main_css_styles',get_theme_file_uri('css/main.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('cadentic_responsive_css_styles',get_theme_file_uri('responsive.css'), false);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js',array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jq-js', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js', array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpdocs-datatables-bootstrap-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpdocs-bootstrap-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
   // wp_enqueue_style('jquery')

    
    
    


    
}
 if( !defined('THEME_IMG_PATH')){
```

define( 'THEME_IMG_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images' );
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cadentic_files');
?>

this is my **functions.php** but some of the js and CSS files are not loading in WordPress 6.0. In **footer.php** I already have wow. init

---

```
                                    //Initiat WOW JS
                                        new WOW().init();   
                            });
                })(jQuery)
            
            
            
            </script>
    
    
    
    
    <?php 
    wp_footer();
    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I tried all the methods and posted here in SOF mostly it did not work in myside unless I add them in **header.php**

```
<title>Welcome to <?php the_title();?></title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:300,400,700|Josefin+Sans:100i,300,400,700|Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/animate.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/owl.theme.default.min.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/owl.carousel.min.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="all" />
        <link href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/jquery-multitabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH; ?>/style.css" media="all" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_CSS_PATH; ?>/main.css" media="all" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH; ?>/responsive.css" media="all" />
```

if I comment out all enqueue scripts  and add this in **function.php**
the above javascripts path works well :

```
if( !defined('THEME_IMG_PATH')){
  define( 'THEME_IMG_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images' );
 }
      if( !defined('THEME_JS_PATH')){
  define( 'THEME_JS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js' );
       if( !defined('THEME_CSS_PATH')){
define( 'THEME_CSS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css' );
}
      if( !defined('THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH')){
define( 'THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
}
 }
```

Comment: Your last code snippet is incomplete, is there a reason you're calling it in a hardcoded script tag that's _above_ the `wp_footer` call? I'm surprised this has worked in the past as most of your enqueued assets do not declare dependencies so the order they're loaded in could be wrong, and you're calling WOW JS manually without declaring any dependencies or using the built in functions WordPress provides for adding inline JS

Comment: Also, I see you're enqueing jQuery from a CDN, this is bad practice and only provided a performance benefit in the 2000's before browser caches were segmented by domain for security reasons. Doing this is more likely to reduce performance and introduce version conflicts between plugins

Comment: But design is breaking during conversion from bootstrap to WordPress theme. @TomJNowell

Comment: I don't understand, you didn't answer any of my questions. Also what is `THEME_CSS_PATH`? Did you check for JS errors in your browsers dev tools?

Comment: `if( !defined('THEME_IMG_PATH')){
  define( 'THEME_IMG_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images' );
 }
      if( !defined('THEME_JS_PATH')){
  define( 'THEME_JS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js' );
       if( !defined('THEME_CSS_PATH')){
define( 'THEME_CSS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css' );
}
      if( !defined('THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH')){
efine( 'THEME_MAIN_CSS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
}
 }`  these are defined in `functins.php`

Comment: please edit your question to include code, multi-line code gets mangled and broken in comments. Did you check your browsers dev tools for javascript error messages?